# Is MIDlet.startApp() guaranteed to be executed fully before MIDlet.pauseApp() or MIDlet.destroyApp() is called?

Tags: java-me, runtime, midp, midlet

[MIdlet's class javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#pauseApp%28%29) states that `MIdlet.destroyApp()` will be called if `MIdlet.startApp()` throws a `RuntimeException`. Assuming no exception is thrown while executing `MIDlet.startApp()`.

**Is `MIDlet.startApp()` guaranteed to be executed fully before `MIDlet.pauseApp()` or `MIDlet.destroyApp()` is called ?**

Example:

MIdlet's class implementation:

```
startApp()
{
  System.out.println("A");
  System.out.println("B");
}

pauseApp()
{
  System.out.println("C");
  System.out.println("D");
}

destroyApp()
{
  System.out.println("E");
  System.out.println("F");
}
```

Output:

```
A
E
F
```

Output (alternative):

```
A
C
D
```

Are the outputs above possible scenarii ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MIDP javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#pauseApp%28%29) answers it

"***If a Runtime exception occurs during startApp() the MIDlet will be destroyed IMMEDIATELY. Its destroyApp() will be called allowing the MIDlet to cleanup.***"

and the similarly for `pauseApp()` and `destroyApp()`.

So answer the OP it is **NOT** guaranteed to execute the method atomically. A `runtime exception` can/will change the state of the MIDlet and in effect the execution flow.